# get row count in single query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in that I want to get the rowcount of records in each column. where column1 is not null column2 is not null column3 is notnull and uID='2'

if the record is like

```
uid   C1    C2    C3
2    Null   3     3
2    2      2     Null
```

the count here is `C1=1, c2=2,c3=1`  How can I do this in one query

Comment: "Aggregate (summary) functions such as COUNT(), MIN(), and SUM() ignore NULL values." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT(colname)` should ignore `NULL` values in the aggregate, so the query should actually be simple.  Note that `COUNT(*)` behaves differently, and does not ignore `NULL` rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(C1), COUNT(C2), COUNT(C3) FROM table WHERE uid=2
```

More information on the `NULL` aggregate behaviors [is found here in the docs.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(C1), COUNT(C2), COUNT(C3)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE uID = 2
    GROUP BY uID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(C1), COUNT(C2), COUNT(C3)
FROM Mytable 
WHERE uid=2
```

By default, it won't count NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

select count(C1), count(C2), count(C3) from table